# How is Persistent Homology different from just calculating ordinary homology at each filtration

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, topological-data-analysis

I apologize if this question is not well-phrased, as I am not very familiar with the subject.

Let say we have a filtration $K^0\subseteq K^1\subseteq K^2\subseteq K^3$.
The $p$-persistent $k$ homology group is defined as: $$H_k^{i,p}=Z_k^i/(B_k^{i+p}\cap Z_k^i)$$
(see the authorative paper by Carlsson titled: Computing Persistent Homology http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.116.2471&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

How is this different from simply calculating the $k$th homology of each filtration, e.g. $H_k(K^1)$, $H_k(K^2)$, etc? This will be able to tell us which cycles are "birth" and "death" which is the key idea of persistent homology, is it not?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What if a cycle is killed on the same level that a new cycle is born? Persistent homology can tell when this happens because it retains information about the 'life' of cycles. Just taking homology at every level of the filtration and comparing ranks won't allow you to see this happening.

Comment: The comment by @DanRust is correct. More formally, to get the persistent homology, you need not only the homology groups of each of the spaces $K^i$ in your filtration but also the homomorphisms between these groups coming from the inclusion maps $K^i\to K^{i+1}$.

Comment: @DanRust Great comment. I missed this fact.